# Azure AD: How to add member to "mail-enabled security group"

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to add a user to Azure AD Group using Graph API.

I can create and update a user, but when i try to add user to a group which is a "mail-enabled security group" i get this error:

> System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceClientException:
>
> Unable to update the specified properties for objects that have originated within an external service

```
{
"odata.error": {
        "code": "Request_BadRequest",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en",
            "value": "Unable to update the specified properties for objects that have originated within an external service."
        },
        "date": "2018-01-04T14:21:20",
        "requestId": "d6c76938-03d3-4668-8f69-2ed227f15063",
        "values": null
    }
}
```

I can add user to a "security" or "Office" member groups, but cannot add a member(user) to "mail enabled security group".

How can i fix this issue?

Here is my code:

```
 public async Task AddGroupMember(IUser newUser)
{
  try
  {
    var grpAlleBrukere = GetAlleBrukere();
    var upn = newUser.UserPrincipalName;
    var grpAlleBrukereId = GetAlleBrukere();
    IGroupFetcher groupFetcher = adClient.Groups.GetByObjectId(grpAlleBrukereId);
    Group group = (Group)groupFetcher.ExecuteAsync().Result;

    if (group.ObjectId != null)
    {
      IUser user = adClient.Users.Where(u => u.UserPrincipalName.Equals(upn, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).ExecuteAsync().Result.CurrentPage.ToArray().First();
      if (user != null)
      {
        //check wather user aleady present into group or not
        IDirectoryObject userExists = group.Members.Where(u => u.ObjectId == user.ObjectId).FirstOrDefault();
        if (userExists == null)
        {
          group.Members.Add(user as DirectoryObject);
          group.UpdateAsync().Wait();
        }
      }
      else
        throw new Exception("User is null.");
    }       
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " + ex.Message);
    Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " + ex.Source);
    Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " + ex.StackTrace);
    Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " + ex.InnerException);
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mind sharing your Request in this question?

Comment: hi i pasted my code above....